# Ударение в слове «репорт»

Tags: орфоэпия

В одном из словарей [указано](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_udarenie/36474/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82), что ударение падает на второй слог. Слово ведь заимствовано из английского языка, в котором ударение падает всегда на первый слог. Как такое возможно? Честно говоря, я всегда говорю репОрт, но нормированным, наверное, должен быть вариант с ударением на Е.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Слово ведь заимствовано из английского языка, в котором ударение
>   падает всегда на первый слог.

В английском ударение далеко не всегда падает на первый слог. Это во французском — там ***всегда*** на последний падает.
И в слове *report* ударение падает как раз на второй слог. Русскими буквами можно передать как *рипОт*. Чтобы убедиться в этом, смотрите [ссылку](http://forvo.com/word/daugherty_report/#en).
В английском полно таких слов (с ударением *не* на первый слог). Например, в одном и том же слове в зависимости от части речи ударение меняется. Например, *record* как существительное — это запись, там ударение на первый слог, а *record* — записывать с ударением на последний слог.

Comment: А с этим словом-то как быть?

Comment: Так я же написал: "И в слове *report*..." Если уж по-английски ударение на второй слог, зачем нам-то ставить на первый?